# Simple Speech Recognition

Tags: software-recommendation, speech-recognition

Is there a simple speech recognition program where you can say a command and that that command will be executed in the terminal? It must be simple to install/setup/configure and it must be a small package because  don't have much space left. I am running Lubuntu 14.10 on my EEE PC 701.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not - there are recognition engines (Sphinx, Julius) but all require a library of speech / meanings - there are several expensive ones out there, and a project to crete an open-source [one](http://www.voxforge.org/home) (which looks to be dead).

Apparently Julius works if you speak Japanese. [Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/download) appears perhaps more promising, with updates this year. I don't think it looks simple though.

Disappointing...

Comment: I don't see why not - I'm not a current user of either, so YMMV, but that sort of use is pretty central to these things

Comment: The expensive library of speech is misinformation. CMUSphinx provides models for several languages. All available in downloads.

Comment: Ah - excellent news! I may go back for another look myself then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net) for that. Tutorial with basics is [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial).

The simple way to configure this would be to use small Python program. You can find example of voice spotting with Python [on CMUSphinx github](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/swig/python/test/kws_test.py).